# List files, read files as links, php?

Tags: javascript, php

This is a strange request I suppose, but I have a directory full of txt files. For example:
- david_smith_interview.txt - 
- beth_martin_interview.txt - 
- sally_smithart_interview.txt

The contents of these text files are a link to their interview in an mp3 format, for example, if you open the file david_smith_interview.txt, it is simply this:

```
http://www.interviews/employees/david_smith.mp3
```

All of the other text files follow the same format. They are simply links to their mp3 interview.

I am trying to use something like below to list the text files:

```
   <?php
     $directory = "/employees/";
     $phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.txt");
        foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
     {
        echo $phpfile; // This will list the files by name
        // How can I output something to reflect this:
        // <a href="http://www.interviews/employees/david_smith.mp3">david_smith_interview</a>
     }
    ?>
```

So I am asking is it possible that the text file can be "read" and used as the actual link?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace _interview.txt with .mp3

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.interviews/employees/" . str_replace("_interview.txt", ".mp3", $phpfile).">" . str_replace(".txt", "", $phpfile). "</a>\";
```

Comment: This works but if I could ask a related follow-up. How do I read the "contents" of the file as a link. Because they won't always be titled and formatted consistently. So How can I pull the contents of the .txt file and use those contents as the link? (knowing that the contents is an actual link)

Answer (score 0):

Since those are .txt files you can just read them one by one to a variable and then echo the result in a for-loop.

In pseudo:

```
$paths fetch_paths()
 $urls = array();
 foreach($paths as $path)
{
    $url=fopen($path);
    array_push($urls,fgets(url)); // Assuming there's only one link per file and it is on one line.
}
foreach($urls as $url)
{
    echo <Your formatted link here>
}
```